# Apply list of functions to rows in another dataframe in R

Tags: r

Friends, I am new to R, however, I am stuck in one of the problems. Thing is, I have a column in dataframe with math functions (mean, min, max etc), and I have another data frame with say same number of rows as functions and I want to apply these specific functions to the data frame.

Below is df with specific math functions

```
  var1   funct
1    A     min
2    B     max
3    C     mean
4    D     min
```

Below if df to which these functions need to be applied (on rows)

```
  a1 b1 c1 d1
1  4  8 12 15
2  NA 9 13 16
3  6 10 NA 17
4  7 11 15 18
```

Suppose the 1st fn needs to be applied to the first row and so on. Can anyone help with this? I have tried do.call, parse(eval) however I failed. Note there was NA, however, I want the results for each row (i.e. exclude NA, but not delete the row itself)

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling your first data frame with functions `df1` and the data frame with data in rows `df2` then,

```
mapply(function(f,x) get(f)(x,na.rm=TRUE), df1$funct, as.data.frame(t(df2)))
```

will produce

```
 min  max mean  min 
   4   16   11    7
```

Comment: Or another one would be `vapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(i) eval(as.name(df1$funct[i]))(unlist(df2[i,]), na.rm=TRUE), numeric(1L))
#[1]  4 16 11  7`

Comment: @akrun If you are going to `eval` then `mapply(function(f,r) eval(call(f,unlist(df2[r,]),na.rm=TRUE)), df1$funct, 1:nrow(df2))`

Comment: Thank you so much guys, this forum is awesome! Thanks a bunch A.Webb, akrun, Jthorpe for pulling in time for this. :)  I might have a late addition to the query, currently working on solving it, but if unable to do so will post it here.

Comment: @tabula_rasa If so, please post as a new question if possible. That's how SO works (it is not a forum).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df2 <- read.csv(textConnection("a1,b1,c1,d1
4,8,12,15
NA,9,13,16
6,10,NA,17
7,11,15,18"))


df1 <- read.csv(textConnection("var1,funct
A,min
B,max
C,mean
D,min"))

df1$funct <- as.character( df1$funct)

x <- mapply(do.call,
       as.list(df1$funct),
       lapply(split(df2,seq(nrow(df2))),
              function(x)list(na.omit(unlist(x)))))
```

(The `lapply(split(...),list))` is because `do.call` requires that it's second argument is a list.)